# Files API to get all symbolic links for a folder

Tags: java, file

```
Folder17
Folder18
Folder19 -> /myfolder/17
Folder20 -> /myfolder/17
```

I have a created symbolic link from `Folder19` to  `Folder17` and `Folder 20` to `Folder17`

I can use `Files.isSymbolicLink(path)` to find whether file is symbolic linked. But is there another way around ? I wanted to know all the folders linked to me. Like, in this case, I want to know all links for `Folder17` which should give me `Folder19` and `Folder20`

I created below have something like below
cd /foo

```
mkdir b
ln -s /foo/b e
ln -s /foo/b f
ln -s /foo/b g
ls -la
    b
    e -> /foo/b
    f -> /foo/b
    g -> /foo/b
```

In my java class, I did below.I  was expecting to return e,f,g  with size 3. But the size is 0

```
    Path path = Paths.get("/foo/b");
    Collection<Path> paths      =  Files.walk(path)
            .filter(Files::isSymbolicLink)
            .filter(p -> {
                try {
                    return path.equals(Files.readSymbolicLink(p));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("log");
                    throw new RuntimeException("An I/O error has occurred!");
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(paths.size());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Good question.  You can probably see why it would be redundant for some file `A` to track every file that is symbolically-linked to `A`, as that could potentially take up a large amount of space.  For that reason, it would be simple to navigate through the directory, checking for symbolic links to file `A`.  You can use something similar to the following:

```
Files.walk(path)
     .filter(Files::isSymbolicLink)
     .filter(p -> {
         try {
             return path.equals(Files.readSymbolicLink(p));
         } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException("An I/O error has occurred!");
         }
     })
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This returns a `List<Path>` containing all of the `Path`s which are symbolic links to `path`.

**Note**: You can use `Files#walkFileTree` to recursively search through these directories if needed.

Comment: You could use [UncheckedIOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) which was designed to be used in lambda expressions.

Comment: Thanks But I got a different behavior when I tried.

Comment: @GauravSinha Can you elaborate?

Comment: @GauravSinha You set your path to `”/foo/b”`, but don’t you want to look inside `”foo”`?